# Add Views to ViewGroup until they fit

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter

I'm using a custom `Adapter` to fill a `ListView`. `ListView` items contain a sort of icon strip - a various number of icons related to the item. My icon strip is a horizontal `LinearLayout`. What I would like to do is to stop adding icons to `LinearLayout` when they don't fit in it anymore and create a new `LinearLayout` instead and icons to it. So basically it's a multiline grid of icons. I'm using API lvl 8.

The problem is that in my `Adapter`'s `bindView` function all layouts are not measured yet and report zeroes as `width`, `height`, `measuredWidth` and `measuredHeight`.

I do not know how to proceed so any help is welcome.

Comment: Are they also zero if you inflate it first?

Comment: The icon strip is inflated as a child in more complex layout in my adapter's newView()